# What captcha for Sinatra?

Tags: sinatra, captcha, recaptcha

What captcha are you using in your Sinatra apps?

I like Google's http://www.google.com/recaptcha, but it seems not for Sinatra (there's a plugin for Rails however). And after googling, plugin such as https://github.com/jpoz/sinatra-recaptcha or https://github.com/bmizerany/sinatra-captcha seems to always have 5 years old...

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using reCaptcha without any plugin is not that hard. See [here for how to display reCaptcha without plugins](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display) and [here for how to verify the user's answer](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify). The API is pretty straightforward. When the user solves the captcha, two parameters will be submitted: `recaptcha_challenge_field` and `recaptcha_response_field`. You can use these to call the verification API from the server and check if the solution is ok. For example:

```
require 'net/http'
require 'json'

post '/check_captcha' do
  res = Net::HTTP.post_form(
    URI.parse('http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/verify'),
    {
      'privatekey' => 'Your private key',
      'remoteip'   => request.ip,
      'challenge'  => params[:recaptcha_challenge_field],
      'response'   => params[:recaptcha_response_field]
    }
  )

  success, error_key = res.body.lines.map(&:chomp)

  if success == 'true'
    # solved the captcha
  else
    # did not solve the captcha
  end
end
```